# BASH - pass status of previous statement to function?

Tags: bash, function, conditional-statements

How do I pass the status of a previous command to a function?

In other words - why do these commands work as expected:

```
$: false && echo "true" || echo "false"
>> false

$: true && echo "true" || echo "false"
>> true
```

But this does not:

```
function status () {
    echo "true" || echo "false"
}

$: true && status
>> true

$: false && status
>>
```

And, how would I get the function above to work as expected?

Comment: `false && echo "true" || echo "false"` is as if it was `(false && echo "true") || echo "false"`, not `false && (echo "true" || echo "false")`, which is what `false && status` is.

Comment: @FelixKling, `false && { echo "true" || echo "false"; }`, rather -- `false && status` doesn't create a subshell as the paren syntax does, so it's able to change variables in the calling shell's scope &c.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:Yeah, I originally included a sentence that `(...)` means precedence in my example, not subshells. Forgot about `{...}`. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the utterly nonportable `function foo() {` (as opposed to the POSIX-compliant `foo() {` or the legacy-ksh-compatible `function foo {`).

Comment: @infinitely_improbable, ...out of curiosity, do you know of any languages where the `&&` in `foo && somefunc` is a short-circuiting operator, but applies only to the first piece of `somefunc` rather than determining whether the whole function runs or not (as a purely binary operation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly test `$?` to get the most-recently-executed command's exit status:

```
status() {
  if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "true"
  else
    echo "false"
  fi
}
```

(This is more reliable than `a && b || c`, which can run *both* `b` and `c` if `a` is true but `b` encounters an error during its execution).

---

Thereafter:

```
$ true; status
true
$ false; status
false
```

---

By the way, I would personally write this in a way that inverts flow control:

```
run_with_status() {
  local retval
  if "$@"; then
    echo "true"
  else
    retval=$?
    echo "false"
    return "$retval"
  fi
}

run_with_status true
run_with_status false
```

That form will play better with `set -e` (which will otherwise exit on errors before ever reaching the ability to print `false`) or `ERR` traps, and avoids potential for bugs where someone adding an `echo` for error logging unintentionally changes the value of `$?`.

Answer (score 2):

Your original statements are being parsed as:

```
( false && echo "true" ) || echo "false"
( true && echo "true" ) || echo "false"
```

It's not executed exactly like this, as there are no subshells, but this shows how the statements are grouped.

When you move the `echo` statements into a function, it's more like this:

```
false && ( echo "true" || echo "false" )
true && ( echo "true" || echo "false" )
```

In this case, the result of `false` or `true` controls the execution of the entire group, not just a single `echo`.

Comment: Would you object to an edit using `{ ...; }` rather than `( ... )` (thus making it pure grouping w/o a subshell)?